# NPE error trying to create button at runtime in expandablelistview android studio

Tags: java, android, button, expandablelistview

I'm trying to create button at runtime in expandablelistview, when you click in one of the elements of the listview

```
     public class ExpandAnimationDemo extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.udiniList);

        final LinearLayout lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item);
        for (int i=0; i<5;i++)
            listAdapter.add("udini"+i);

        // create the layout params that will be used to define how your
        // button will be displayed

      LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        // Create Button
        final Button btn = new Button(this);
        // Give button an ID
        //btn.setId(j+1);
        btn.setText("Add To Cart");
        // set the layoutParams on the button
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);
        //Add button to LinearLayout
        ll.addView(btn);

        //Add button to LinearLayout defined in XML
        lm.addView(ll); here i have de null pointer!



        list.setAdapter(listAdapter);



        // Creating an item click listener, to open/close our toolbar for each item
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {


                View toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);



                // Creating the expand animation for the item
                ExpandAnimation expandAni = new ExpandAnimation(toolbar, 500);

                // Start the animation on the toolbar
                toolbar.startAnimation(expandAni);
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * A simple implementation of list adapter.
     */
    class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }

            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(getItem(position));


            // Resets the toolbar to be closed
            View toolbar = convertView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin = -50;
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

but I get a null pointer exception

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.udinic.expand_animation_example.ExpandAnimationDemo.onCreate(ExpandAnimationDemo.java:51)
>   ---> here  lm.addView(ll);

Comment: R.id.toolbar existing in main.xml

Comment: first of all, thanks for taking the time to answer me, you were right, but does not show me anything, because obviously where I want to be displayed is list_item.xml which is where you will find the R.id.toolbar, how can i do? I am new at this

Comment: If all the lm variable related one is belongs to list_item right? Then this code should be in the adapter not in activity. The activity is loaded main.xml, where R.id.toolbar is not existing and ur trying to use it. So, it has thrown NPE. Check putting sysout below lm variable, u can see the object is null.